In js running in a devcontainer, how can I copy something to the host clipboard?
My objective is to run a node.js CLI inside my devcontainer. I want to copy some text to the host clipboard inside the container.
This was super simple before running in a devcontainer, because on Mac OS I could call pbcopy like this:
import { exec } from 'node:child_process';
const child = exec(command);

    if (child.stdin) {
        child.stdin.end(text); // This sends the text to the command's stdin
    }
}

But this does not work in devcontainers. Tried with xclip but get:
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :1

Did anyone manage to get this to work?

Libraries like clipboardy for Node.js can help abstract the clipboard access and might work within your devcontainer setup.
import clipboardy from 'clipboardy';

async function copyToClipboard(text) {
    try {
        await clipboardy.write(text);
        console.log('Text copied to clipboard successfully!');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error copying to clipboard:', err);
    }
}

copyToClipboard('Text to copy');

